# Search text function in excel to return the following value instead of "yes" "no"

Tags: excel, vba, function, macros

Currently I am using =IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*vendor number*",I2,1)),"NO","YES ") to return a yes no value if the vendor number is present within a single cell. Cells have no specific format(in regards to consistency of data) so this is the only way to pull them that I have  found. My goal is to pull the actual vendor number that follows the text "vendor number". The Vendor number has 10 digits as I assume that is necessary.Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance excel guru's

EDIT: SAMPLE DATA

```
"2015-11-05 20:00:51 - Guest Guest (Additional comments (Customer Visible))
received from: xxxxx@xxxx.com

Vendor Name:  AAAA BBBB
Vendor Number: 1234567890
Address:  1000 main street
Contact Name:  Gary Busey
Telephone #  123-456-8888
Email address:  XXX@XXX.com
"
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT: 1234567890

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: For example: the cell that contains the text I am searching for has dates, times, notes, etc.. But within the cell you will find " Vendor Number 0000000000 " I want to find the vendor number and then pull the 10 digit number that follows the words " Vendor Number"

Comment: some test data and expected output would be nice.

Comment: I will add some info shortly, I need to remove private information.

Comment: That is all in one cell?

Comment: yep, its a data dump from ServiceNow

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  You may need to refresh the page to see it, I temporarily deleted it as I  worked on it.

Comment: it worked perfectly! I picked this project up this morning...found out the vendor number might not be 10 digit. and the vendor number can come in 4 different formats

vendor no.
vendor Number
vendor #
vendor Number:

I do not know how to do this without a column for each...Any suggestions?-I know this has expanded beyond the original scope of my question :/

My goal was to get it right and then record the macro and make adjustments as needed.

I can make the adjustments confidently now that you have given me the proper function.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is always 10 digits and always after a space after the words "Vendor Number:" then you can use this:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(I2,SEARCH("vendor number: ",I2)+LEN("vendor number: "),10)),"")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I have a meeting, I will try this asap and get back to you. Looks great though!